Gradle download issues
I recently downloaded android studio koala to begin app development, but gradle download/sync times out repeatedly when trying to build/download gradle file 8.0-bin. I have disabled anti-virus, disabled windows defender, cleared cache, and redownloaded studio multiple times yet the problem persists. What am I doing wrong, and can someone be so kind to remote login to my system to see what could be the issue, please? I've been on this now for almost 2 months.
Have disabled the following: Windows defender, quick-heal antivirus, cleared cache, and reinstalled android studio repeatedly.

so i had the exact same problem today and everytime it gave me connection timeout. i mostly use vpn (because of restrictions in my country) and also use proxy to proxy my vpn connection to android studio. i figured that it needs super stable network and i used socks proxy instead of http proxy so it is faster and more stable.
it seems like gradle closes unstable connection or network activity and thats why it gives you timeout.
at least thats what i encountered.
hope it helps :)
